# How to escape special charcters and insert a string after mathing string in same line using sed

Tags: shell, sed

I want to edit a file in place from command line.
I have file content as below and want to add new string `sendonly();` after `localhost(abc);`.

```
localhost(abc); dest(def);
```

After modidify the above line, it should look like below.

```
localhost(abc); sendonly(); dest(def);
```

I am running command:

```
sed -e 's/\blocalhost(abc);\b/& sendonly();/' f4.txt
```

But not getting required output. If I try to escape special characters, getting error as unmatched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\b` matches if the character before it is a word character and the one after it is not, or vice-versa. A "word" character is any letter or digit or the underscore character. The second `\b` is between a `;` and , both are non word characters, so it does not match.

This should be your `sed`:

```
sed 's/\blocalhost(abc);/& sendonly();/'
```